# Adding compile flags for multiple targets in XCode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4

I have a app that has multiple targets. Each target has different features. Where and how do I define complier flags so that when I build each target will only have the features that I assign to it.

For instance I like to do something like this.

```
#ifdef APP1

#define FEATURE_A
#define FEATURE_B

#elif APP2

#define FEATURE_B

#else

#endif
```

Where would I put `#define APP1` or `#define APP2`. APP1 and APP2 are the bundle IDs of the apps. I would like to do it so that the definitions are not defined dynamically when the application runs (i.e. should not be in an if statement), but rather set when I build the application.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: how to use PREPROCESSOR Flags (like \`#if DEBUG\`) to implement API keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38813906/swift-how-to-use-preprocessor-flags-like-if-debug-to-implement-api-keys)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put corresponding definition in target's settings, 'Preprocessor Macros' section.

Comment: And if you want to share stuff between targets or projects, you can put them in .xcconfig files.