# How can I differentiate between multiple targets in xcode at runtime

Tags: ios, xcode, target

Working on an old objective c application where in I need to create multiple targets. Question is how do I differentiate between multiple targets run time in the code and accordingly I need to load the resources from bundle.

Comment: By using bundle Identifer - if you use different bundle identifiers for both targets.

Answer (score 1):

Project > Build Settings > Preprocessor Macros

define there different macros for different targets e.g.:

- TARGET_1
- TARGET_2

and in code you can diferenciate it like this:

```
NSString *pathToMyResource = nil;

#ifdef TARGET_1
  pathToMyResource = @"pathToMyResourceForTarget1";
#else
  pathToMyResource = @"pathToMyResourceForTarget2";
#endif
```

EDIT: added swift syntax

```
#if DEBUG
  let apiKey = "KEY_A"
#else
  let apiKey = "KEY_B"
#endif
```

see here: [Swift 3: how to use PREPROCESSOR Flags (like `#if DEBUG`) to implement API keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38813906/swift-3-how-to-use-preprocessor-flags-like-if-debug-to-implement-api-keys)

Comment: Pl. suggest the same for swift also

Answer (score 1):

You can use @matloob's answer. Below is an another approach.

You can also use Preprocessing for differentiating among targets.

Please have a look at following tutorial. This may also help you.

Reference :
[Target Differentiation dynamically - Appcoda](http://www.appcoda.com/using-xcode-targets/)