# Is there is any way to create a IOS app as build for another app?

Tags: ios, build-settings

I have an IOS app which holds lot of Configuration settings to use the app and also this app is used in 5 warehouses, settings will be differ from one warehouse to another warehouse. So it becomes more painful for the users using this app.. Even ever they install the app then need to set the configuration settings.

So my problem is If i hardcode the settings value, it is very difficult to maintain the code for all the different warehouse. if i do small change in my app have to change in all of the 5 source code.. Even if i decide to maintain 1 code .. i have to change the setting value every time before setting the build.. It is more painful for me.

so my question is..

Is there any way to run a app and set values in configuration settings. And generate this setting app as a build ?? i don't know it will workout or not please share me some ideas..

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to have 1 source code and there is possibility to create different Targets. Each target can have it's own configuration plist file and you can set also different preprocessor macros for each target.

How to use preprocesor macros you can see here: [How can I differentiate between multiple targets in xcode at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43868820/how-can-i-differentiate-between-multiple-targets-in-xcode-at-runtime/43868944#43868944)

How to create targets you can see here: [Add preprocessor macro to a target in xcode 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26928622/add-preprocessor-macro-to-a-target-in-xcode-6)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have one app with different [targets](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Targets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009328-CH4-SW1) and [schema](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Schemes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009328-CH8-SW1). Then just google it there's many articles about.

Answer (score 0):

One more possibility (besides targets) is to create a shared library and if you want to apply some configs after installation you can prompt user to download one from a server (for instance)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create different schemas.

For example, you can create an application for Development, Staging, Production.

You can have configurations in plist file and make it variable according to the schemas.

When your application opens it will take the values according to the schema with which it was built.

Follow this [guide](https://zeemee.engineering/how-to-set-up-multiple-schemes-configurations-in-xcode-for-your-react-native-ios-app-7da4b5237966) to create different schemas.

Also, you can integrate [Fastlane](https://fabric.io/features/distribution?utm_campaign=fastlane.tools) to generate builds easily with different schemas with simple commands.