# Conditional compiling in Swift

Tags: ios, swift3, conditional-compilation

I want to use flags to control the compiler in Swift. Like we use #ifdef, #ifndef, #else, #endif in C (and C++, Objective C, ....)

I found the way to do it on the net, but I hit a problem in the following case. Anyone reading will understand what I want.
Nevertheless the compiler complains. What is the way to go around? Of course without having to copy two times the same ten or more lines.

```
#if UseAds
class ViewController: UIViewController,XYZBannerDelegateProtocol {
#else
class ViewController: UIViewController {
#endif
```

Note that I got the information I am using here:
http://en.swifter.tips/condition-compile/
which is similar to what can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38813906/swift-3-how-to-use-preprocessor-flags-like-if-debug-to-implement-api-keys).

But none of these solves my problem. They only tell me the basic way to do it.

Comment: Have you defined the UseAds value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 3: how to use PREPROCESSOR Flags (like \`#if DEBUG\`) to implement API keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38813906/swift-3-how-to-use-preprocessor-flags-like-if-debug-to-implement-api-keys)

Comment: Yes I have defined the UseAds value.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. Please see my updated post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use like this :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // Your common functions
}
#if UseAds
    extension ViewController: XYZBannerDelegateProtocol {
        // Your delegate methods    
    }
#endif
```