# How to jump controller through debugging

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Yes we all know `navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)` used for pushing controller. I want to ask is there any way that we can jump to `ViewController` on debugging?

For ex. -

```
func jump() {
   let vc = ViewController(nibName: "ViewController",bundle: nil)//here breakpoint set
   //navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

can we uncomment  `pushViewController` dynamically (using debugging or any technique.)?

Comment: Why not set a breakpoint in the pushed view controller, like in viewDidLoad? Is there something about the push you need to debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can use,

1. place a breakpoint at  `let vc = ViewController(nibName: "ViewController",bundle: nil)//here breakpoint set`
2. click the "Next" button for debug and in debug window paste this
   line using po command and press enter.
   `po navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)`

and now press the play button of debugging..it will execute your code.

Comment: Doesn't know that even exist. :)

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of your question: You can use compilation conditions to only execute the command in certain targets.
Like in the MyApp-Debug you would do it but in MyApp-Release the code woulnd't be executed.

```
#if DEBUG
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
#endif
```

Refer to this thread for more detailed information: 
[Swift: how to use PREPROCESSOR Flags (like `#if DEBUG`) to implement API keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38813906/swift-how-to-use-preprocessor-flags-like-if-debug-to-implement-api-keys)