# Adding variables at build time in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, build, environment-variables

I have some dynamic values I need to change based on the type of build I am doing in Xcode.

I have created 2 schemes `DEV` and `PROD` and set environment variables in each

[image]

I then consume these in code as follows

```
var serviceDomain: String {
    let envVar = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment
    guard let value = envVar["APP_SERVICE_DOMAIN"] else { fatalError("Missing APP_SERVICE_DOMAIN enviroment variable") }
    return value
}
```

Is this the correct way to approach this?

Once an app is compiled, should these values now be bundled with it?

I have an issue in that once I've stopped my simulator, if I try to open an app built this way, it crashes and I suspect the environment variables aren't present anymore.

**In short, I would like a build for dev that uses one set of variables and a build for release / production that uses another.**

Comment: Regarding environment vars scope, you are right: they are defined by Xcode and, as such, won’t be be present when running your app outside the IDE. You will need to define *default values* in your code (or an external file) if you want to follow this approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need environment variables at all!

Go to build settings and search for active compilation conditions:

[image]

Add `DEBUG` for Debug and `RELEASE` for Release as I have done here.

Then declare your variables. Let's say you want `a` to be 1 in release mode, and 2 in debug mode,

```
#if RELEASE
let a = 1
#elseif DEBUG
let a = 2
#endif
```

And that's it!

The compiler will choose one of the values to compile, depending on your scheme's Build Configuration. Here, it is debug, so 2 will be used:

[image]

[More details on this `#if` thingy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38813906/swift-how-to-use-preprocessor-flags-like-if-debug-to-implement-api-keys/47395485)

Comment: Thank you, so I should use that if statement in perhaps some sort of constants file I assume?

Comment: @HarryBlue Yes you could put it in a constant file, or anywhere else you like. It doesn't matter.